# How to find a specific text in a textarea, move to it and mark it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[image]

I have some json arrays filling them in a several drop-down lists.And I have loaded SQL stored procedure text body in a textarea as image. to able the user to edit the stored procedure without accessing the SQL server.
what I am asking about is it possible to find and match the selected value of a drop-down list within the textarea and move the screen to it and highlight the matched text.

```
<div class="widget-content" style="        height: calc(100vh - 63px); overflow: auto;">

    <div class="form-group" id="field3">
        <label class="title_lable">CMDs :</label>
        <select data-placeholder="Choose a CMD" ng-model="cmd"
                id="chosenValueID1" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2"
                ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in cmds"
                ng-click="selectedWord = cmd">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="field3">
        <label class="title_lable">Sheet Management :</label>
        <select data-placeholder="Choose a Sheet" ng-model="sheet"
                id="chosenValueID2" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2"
                ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in sheetsmanagement"
                ng-click="$parent.selectedWord = sheet">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="field3">
        <label class="title_lable">Resource List :</label>
        <select data-placeholder="Choose a Resource" ng-model="resource"
                id="chosenValueID3" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2"
                ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in resourcelist"
                ng-click="$parent.selectedWord = resource">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="field3">
        <label class="title_lable">Important :</label>
        <select data-placeholder="Choose an Important" ng-model="imp"
                id="chosenValueID4" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2"
                ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in important"
                ng-click="$parent.selectedWord = imp">
        </select>
    </div>

    <!--<div style="border: red thin solid; width: 1000px; padding: 10px;" ng-bind-html-unsafe="text | highlightWord : selectedWord"> {{proceduretext}}</div>
    </div>Selected Word: {{selectedWord}}-->
    <textarea rows="30" cols="180" ng-model="proceduretext" 
              ng-bind-html-unsafe="text | highlightWord : selectedWord">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$scope.sheetsmanagement = [
    { id: 1, name: 'AssignSheet' },
    { id: 2, name: 'DelAssignSheet' },
    { id: 3, name: 'DelAssignSheetProc' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DelAssignSheetTempl' },
    { id: 5, name: 'AssigSheetTemp' },
    { id: 6, name: 'GetEmptySlotsEx' },
    { id: 7, name: 'getsessions' },
    { id: 8, name: 'getsessionno' },
    { id: 9, name: 'canceleval' },
    { id: 10, name: 'UPDSTATUS' },
    { id: 11, name: 'REQLIST' },
    { id: 12, name: 'PRSLIST' },
    { id: 13, name: 'WRKLIST' },
    { id: 14, name: 'BOKLIST' },
    { id: 15, name: 'SRVLIST' },
    { id: 16, name: 'ServWithSheet' },
    { id: 17, name: 'SETORDER' }
]
```

i have tried to use filter in angularjs but it didnt work with me

```
.filter('highlightWord', function () {
    return function (text, selectedWord) {
        if (selectedWord) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(selectedWord, "g");
            return text.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlighted">' + selectedWord + '</span>');
        }
        else {
            return text;
        }
    };
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean highlighting in a way that you select some of the content OR make the background color some color? Because the latter is not really possible in a regular textarea. Maybe [this quirksmode](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) article is of some help.

Comment: Thanks for replying , I mean the background color of the matched text with the selected item text from the drop downlist

Comment: Yes. Changing the background color of specific text is not possible in textarea. You could either mimic your own textarea with a div with listeners to update the text on key down and on focus. Or use something like tinymce where you can can achieve much more.

Comment: This is not possible while the textarea is editable. Maybe there are some components on the web that could achieve this behaviour.

Comment: so do you suggest another way to reach the same target.

Comment: Also can't use `ng-bind-html` with `ng-model` on textarea